# How to make an upload script in php mysqli of a csv format file and has a content validation in it?

Tags: php, regex, validation, csv, file-upload

This is my script for the upload part, how can I add a content validation of csv upload ? Can anyone help ?

```
<?php

    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '4M');



    $filename = $_POST['filename'];

    if(!isset($_FILES['filename'])){
        echo "No file selected";
    } 
    else{

        $error=array();
        $extension=array("xlsx","csv");
        foreach($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)
        {
            echo "<br/>Filename: ".$file_name=$_FILES["filename"]["name"][$key];
            echo "<br/>Temporary: ".$file_tmp=$_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            echo "<br/>Size: ".$size=$_FILES["filename"]["size"][$key];
            echo "<br/>Extension: ".$ext=pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(in_array($ext,$extension))
            {

                    if(!file_exists("/var/www/html/phpsample/".$file_name)){
                        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"][$key], "/var/www/html/phpsample/".$file_name)){
                               //echo "Success on File Not Exist";
                             $insert = insertFile($file_name);
                               if($insert){
                                    header("location: index.php?success=true");
                               }
                                else{
                                    echo mysql_error();
                                }

                        //echo "File Not Exist";
                        //echo "<br/>Error: ".$error = $_FILES["filename"]["error"][$key];
                        //echo "<br/>php info: ".phpinfo();
                        }

                    }

                    else
                        {
                            $filename=basename($file_name,$ext);
                            $newFileName=$filename.time().".".$ext;
                            if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"][$key], "/var/www/html/phpsample/".$newFileName)){
                                //echo "Success on File Exist";
                                $insert = insertFile($newFileName);
                                if($insert){
                                    header("location: index.php?success=true");
                                }
                            }
                            //echo "File Exist";
                        }

               //echo "Extension of file is in our array list";
            }

            else{
                //array_push($error,"$file_name, ");
                echo "The file you upload is not included in allowed file extension list.";
            }

        }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: your file uploaded or not?

Comment: You could try to parse the uploaded file with [`fgetcvs`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgetcsv.php) and check if it matches your requirements.

Comment: my file upload is working, but i need to validation the content of my csv file

Comment: please i just need to make my code work now. can anyone help ?

Comment: @ZacharyCampaner Have you tried my idea in the comment above?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER yes i tried it but i only get the contents in an array that the whole array elements would be validation, example , this is my array , ÊÊ,013224-001,1,"PCA,DDR2-800,MINIDIMM MOD256MBx 40",BOM,ASSY,ID121608ZS
ÊÊ,122657-00A,1,SOFTWARE TEST (US M3 CTO),BOM,ASSY,
ÊÊ,376383-002,8,"ASSY, BLANK,SFF",BOM,ASSY,
ÊÊ,458943-003,1,"CA ASSY, SFP BATTERY, 15 POS, 28AWG, 24",BOM,ASSY,
ÊÊ,460499-001,1,"ASSY, 4/V650HT BATTERY CHARGER MODULE",BOM,ASSY,
ÊÊ,499256-001,2,"ASSY, BLANK,MEDIA BAY,ML350G6",BOM,ASSY,
ÊÊ,500203-061,2,"DIMM,4GB PC3-10600R,256Mx4,RoHS",BOM,ASSY,RAKWF8DXV2Q100,

Comment: I want to validate the number part that to limit it to just 4 numbers only.

Comment: Well then now check your array against your specs. And et voilà you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file using [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) as follows and do validation inside the loop.

See the following example code.

```
$fileData=fopen($filename, 'r');

while(!feof($fileData))
{
   //do validation for fgetcsv($file) value here
  if($i%5 == 0){
       if(is_numeric(fgetcsv($file)) && strlen(fgetcsv($file)) == 4){
           return true;
       }
       else{
             return false;
       }
   } 
   $i++;
   print_r(fgetcsv($file));
}
```

Comment: example this are the elements in the csv file that i need to validate

Comment: MOBILE_NUMBER
CUSTOMER_NAME
LINK
RATE
TYPE

Comment: You only need to validate mobile number field?

Comment: not mobile number only, also the customer name, the link , the rate and the type

Comment: As you have 5 fields, 0th,5th,10th etc... element is mobile number.then you can apply mobile number validation to those fields.you can do the validation for other fields using the multiples like that.

Comment: i just need to know if how i would insert the validation in your code

Comment: I added a validation for mobile_number fields.I didn't run the code.please check like above for all the fields.

Comment: what if i need ot validate all that i had given elements ?

Comment: not all the elements, validate fields you want.if you want to validate only mobile number above code can be used.otherwise add the validations for other fields you want.